# Problems with tornado webserver file download

Tags: python, tornado

I am creating a piece of conversion software in python, and I am making it as a tornado webserver. My plan is to have the converted file download from the server. I found some example code online for this. My main issue is that this is my first time using tornado and I have limited knowledge of what I am doing.

Here is the example code.

```
def post(self,filename):
    print('i download file handler : ',filename)

    ifile  = open(filename+".csv", "r")
    self.set_header ('Content-Type', 'text/csv')
    self.set_header ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='+filename+'')
    self.write (ifile.read())
```

Here is my code:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import os

print "If at any point you wish to quit the program hit Ctrl + C"

filetype = raw_input("What kind of file would you like to convert? Audio, Image, Video or Document: ")

if filetype == "Document":
   path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
   os.chdir(path[1:-2])
   filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
   Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. txt: ")
   from subprocess import check_call
   check_call(["unoconv", "-f", Fileextension, filename])

elif filetype == "Audio":
   path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
   os.chdir(path[1:-2])
   filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
   Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. mp3: ")
   body, ext = os.path.splitext("filename")
   from subprocess import check_call
   check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename, body + "." + Fileextension])

elif filetype == "Video":
   path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
   os.chdir(path[1:-2])
   filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
   Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. mp4: ")
   body, ext = os.path.splitext("filename")
   from subprocess import check_call
   check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename, body + "." + Fileextension])

elif filetype == "Image":
   path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
   os.chdir(path[1:-2])
   filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
   Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. JPG: ")
   body, ext = os.path.splitext("filename")
   from subprocess import check_call    
   check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename, body + "." + Fileextension])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(7777)
try:
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

If anyone has a solution to this that would be great. Example code would be best, but at this point anything would be useful.

Comment: @reggaeguitar There is no real issue, I would just like some advice on how I could use that example code to make it so that the file is put up onto a the webserver to be downloaded, rather than directly downloaded to the computer.